# computed headers, define не обнаружен

Tags: c, include

Начал разбираться с computed headers в си и столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть файлы **"main_file.h"**, **"funcs_file.h"**, **"main_file.c"**, **"funcs_file.c"**

Содержимое **"main_file.c"**

```
#include "main_file.h"
/* some code */
```

Содержимое **"main_file.h"**

```
#ifndef MAIN
#  define MAIN "main_file.h"
#    ifndef FUNCS
#      define FUNCS "funcs_file.h"
#    endif
#    include <stdio.h>
#    include <malloc.h>    
#endif
```

Содержимое **"func_file.h"**

```
    #define SIZE 1

/* объявление некоторых функций */
```

В коде файлов **"main_file.c"** и **"func_file.c"** пытаюсь использовать `SIZE`, однако VS пишет -

> SIZE: необъявленный идентификатор.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно и подскажите, как лучше всего в таком случае организовать файлы.

Comment: Так а где сами `#include` для ваших computed headers? Зачем вы их "компутили", если вы не используете результаты этого "компутинга"?

Comment: добавлю, что такой хак как *computed includes* используется, по старой поговорке, чуть чаще, чем никогда в современном мире...

Answer (score 1):

Например, берем main_file.c...

Его содержимое -

```
#include "main_file.h"
```

Т.е.

```
#ifndef MAIN
#  define MAIN "main_file.h"
#    ifndef FUNCS
#      define FUNCS "funcs_file.h"
#    endif
#    include <stdio.h>
#    include <malloc.h>    
#endif
```

Поскольку никакой `MAIN` до начала не определен, имеем по сути

```
#define MAIN "main_file.h"
#define FUNCS "funcs_file.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
```

Отлично, но где вы тут видите `SIZE`, чтоб его использовать?

И, кстати, что вы хотите добиться вот этими строками:

```
#define MAIN "main_file.h"
#define FUNCS "funcs_file.h"
```

?

Comment: Спасибо, я что-то упустил из виду включение. Ну на самом деле, я хотел дальше в других заголовочных файлах использовать уже макро-определения вместо полных имён файлов

Comment: @Setplus, поверьте, это не то место, в котором нужно экономить нажатия на кнопки. А проблем огрести можно выше крыши, и ещё с хорошей такой горкой. Даже могильником. Как только ваш код выйдет за пределы localhost и "игрушечных" проектов...